# Electron ipcMain.handle() is not firing when the expected result changes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, electron

My app opens two windows, one which is supposed to go on a projector (second monitor). I am trying to make it function so that if the app opens without a projector connected, the user has the ability to connect a projector, then click a button and push the second window. If they try to click the button without a projector connected, they are notified with an `alert`. Once they connect the projector and click the button, it will then push the window to the other screen as expected and maximize itself.

- Here is what works:

1. I open the app with two monitors. I click the projector connected button. The window is pushed and maximized.
2. I open the app with one monitor. I click the projector connected button. The alert pops up and tells me the projector isn't connected. I can do this multiple times.
3. I open the app with one monitor. I **do not** click the projector connected button. I switch my display mode to two monitors. I click the projector connected button. The window is pushed and maximized.

- Here is what doesn't work:

I open the app with one monitor. I **do** click the projector connected button. The alert pops up and tells me the projector isn't connected. I switch my display options to two monitors. I click the projector connected button. **Nothing happens.** No alerts, console logs, nothing.

Here is my code:

electron.js:

```
const electron = require("electron");
const app = electron.app;
const BrowserWindow = electron.BrowserWindow;
const path = require("path");
const isDev = require("electron-is-dev");
const { ipcMain } = require("electron");

let mainWindow;
let gameWindow;
let projectorDisplay;
const electronScreen = electron.screen;

function createWindow() {

    mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 900,
        height: 680,
        title: "Control Panel",
        webPreferences: {
            nodeIntegration: true,
        },
    });
    gameWindow = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 1200,
        height: 900,
        webPreferences: {
            nodeIntegration: true,
        },
        frame: false,
        title: "Gameboard",
        show: true,
    });

    mainWindow.loadURL(
        isDev
            ? "http://localhost:3000"
            : `file://${path.join(__dirname, "../build/index.html")}`
    );
    
    mainWindow.on("closed", () => {
        gameWindow.close();
        mainWindow = null;
        gameWindow = null;
        app.quit();
    });

    ipcMain.handle("REQUEST_PROJECTOR_MODE", async () => {
        let promise = new Promise((resolve) => {
            projectorDisplay = electronScreen.getAllDisplays().find((display) => {
                return display.bounds.x !== 0 || display.bounds.y !== 0;
            });
            if (projectorDisplay !== undefined) {
                gameWindow.setBounds({
                    x: projectorDisplay.bounds.x + 50,
                    y: projectorDisplay.bounds.y + 50,
                });
                gameWindow.maximize();
                resolve(true);
            } else {
                resolve(false);
            }
        });
        return await promise;
    });

    gameWindow.loadURL(
        isDev
            ? "http://localhost:3000/#/gameboard"
            : `file://${path.join(__dirname, "../build/index.html")}`
    );

    gameWindow.webContents.executeJavaScript("location.assign('#/gameboard');");
}

app.on("ready", createWindow);
// other unrelated things...
```

Here is (part of) my renderer component:

```
projectorMode = () => {
        ipcRenderer.invoke("REQUEST_PROJECTOR_MODE")
            .then((response) => {
                if(response === true) {
                    this.hideProjectorButton()
                } else {
                    alert('Projector not found')
                }
            })
    };

hideProjectorButton = () => {
        this.projectorButton.current.style.display = "none";
    };
```

Comment: hi @Bender 
Sorry to bother you, but I have a question if you can help me. I am working on a desktop application project that displays images and when I scroll the image up it appears to me in the projector, I use the electron and  react and I do not see any content related to an idea about the topic other than this question, do you have an idea or an article about this

Comment: Sorry @Elabbasy00 I don't really understand your question, but if you make your own SO post, provide (a lot) more details and some code, I might be able to take a look.

Comment: I am grateful for your response, I found a solution that I have not fully tried yet and used part of your code if it fails, I will create my own post

Answer (score 0):

I figured out my problem. It seems like calling an `ipcRenderer` function from a window that is not the main BrowserWindow can cause some weird side effects. I stripped all the code down to simply send and receive basic messages, and even they were failing in unpredictable ways. Once I put the "projector mode" request on a button in the main window, all the problems disappeared and the app works as intended.